# How to create new users after MongDB Container creation with admin user-pwd and admin DB

Tags: mongodb, containers, user-management

We are creating a MongoDB container with Azure IoT Deployments where we are able to create an admin user and password using environment variables. It's a Ubuntu 20.04 machine.

Later, by user interaction or messaging, we will obtain new DB and user information and need to set up users and databases based on the received information.

Can we run a bash script passing the user-pwd-DB information so the script can create them interacting with the MongoDB running in the container? We can run the script on a background process on the same machine but we cannot have the user open a console, login into the MongoDB shell within the container, and create users.

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to run scripts to perform MongoDB shell operations.

1. Install MongoDB client - `apt install mongodb-client`
2. Run command like so (assuming you have exposed the port on MongoDB server running inside container):

   mongo testdb --port 27017 --authenticationDatabase admin <<EOF
   use admin;
   db.createUser(
   {
   user: 'user1',
   pwd: 'pass1',
   roles: [
   {
   role: 'readWrite',
   db: 'testdb'
   }
   ],
   passwordDigestor:'server'
   }
   )
   EOF